# iTunes locks up (library on NAS)

Tags: itunes, nas

iTunes continually locks up on me.  I have my library set to an external NAS, and I only launch iTunes when connected to this NAS.  Any ideas why iTunes locks up - is it related to the library not being on my PC?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that it locks up because the iTunes library is located on the NAS is likely correct. Some NAS's offer a setting/app to run an iTunes-Server. If your NAS offers something like that you should use that instead of just putting the library on a shared drive. (E.g. http://qnap.com/en/index.php?lang=en&sn=2674)

If your NAS doesn't have iTunes Server functionality you could try going through the NAS settings and see if there are power-saving options like "spinning down the harddrive" that you can disable. By disabling those settings the NAS will remain active all the time and there will be less of a delay when iTunes tries get the next track etc.

*If you need more help you should post the exact model of your NAS and people may be able to tell you something more specific.*

Comment: Its a Seagate GoFlex NAS.  I believe your answer is correct though - I will give it a try and see if Seagate supports iTunes Server functionality.  Thank you for the answer